# Failing to understand Gradle's default dependency resolution strategy

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have built and uploaded a Java library to a private Artifactory space. Let's say the library has a Gradle identifier of `com.mycompany:MyLibrary:1.0.0`, has been uploaded to https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release and does not exist in JCenter. This library has a dependency on another library which is *not* uploaded to https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release but is openly available from JCenter. Let's say this second library has a Gradle identifier of `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0`.

As a consumer of the Java library in a Java application, my list of dependencies is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mycompany:MyLibrary:1.0.0'
}
```

Notably, I do not need to explicitly declare the `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0` dependency since it will be resolved transitively.

Further, for reasons of security, I want to order my private Artifactory repository above JCenter, as follows:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

However, when I try to build my Java application, I am met with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find jsr305-3.0.0.jar (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.jar
```

It appears from this error that the `jsr305-3.0.0` artifact was only searched for in my private Artifactory repository and not in JCenter. I would have expected Gradle to search for the `jsr305-3.0.0` artifact in JCenter if it could not be found in my private Artifactory repository.

If I reorder the repositories so that JCenter is declared first, as follows...

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    }
}
```

... then the build completes successfully.

Is what I am experiencing the expected behaviour for how Gradle resolves dependencies or is this a bug? If it's the expected behaviour, is there anything I can do to change the dependency resolution strategy so that I can declare my private Artifactory repository above JCenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns that at some point in the past my private Artifactory instance created a partial cache of JCenter. I'm not sure how this cache came to be but it seems to include all of the artifacts which my library depends on. Further, the cache only includes the pom and sources jar of each artifact and not its binary jar, as follows:

[image]

So what's happening when a consumer of my library orders his/her repositories as follows...

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    }
    jcenter()
}
```

... is that Gradle is finding the pom file for `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0` in `https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release` and it's expecting to find the binary jar there also. When it does not find the binary jar there, it fails the build. Note in particular that Gradle will only proceed to search for an artifact in the next repository in the list (JCenter in this example) if it does not find the pom file for it in any of the previous repositories that it has inspected.

The solution for me is to either remove the JCenter cache from my private Artifactory instance or to make the cache complete so that it includes the binary jar file for each artifact that it holds.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata in JCenter is better than the metadata in your custom private Artifactory space.

Gradle checks all repositories to find the best metadata and uses that.

Check out the following quotes from the [Declaring Repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) page in the Gradle documentation.

Firstly, from the [Declaring Multiple Repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_multiple_repositories) section:

> The order of declaration determines how Gradle will check for
> dependencies at runtime. If Gradle finds a module descriptor in a
> particular repository, it will attempt to download all of the
> artifacts for that module from the same repository. You can learn more
> about the inner workings of dependency downloads.

Secondly, from the [Supported Repository Types](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:repository-types) section:

> As Gradle prefers to use modules whose descriptor has been created
> from real meta-data rather than being generated, flat directory
> repositories cannot be used to override artifacts with real meta-data
> from other repositories declared in the build.
>
> For example, if Gradle finds only jmxri-1.2.1.jar in a flat directory
> repository, but jmxri-1.2.1.pom in another repository that supports
> meta-data, it will use the second repository to provide the module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your answer and the quote you provided, I can't understand why changing the order of my repositories is important in determining whether the dependency resolution will be successful or not. If you can provide some further information on this, that would be great. Otherwise, I'll spend some more time reading the link that you shared and reading up on what a "module descriptor" is.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer and the quotes and the link that you provided. It didn't answer my question directly but it was useful reading and helped me get to the answer of my problem. For anyone else stumbling across this thread, I also found the [Dependency Management with Gradle](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLLQbIfXVLZqEdJ-6tEsfvn17IKCeQOGWf) playlist in the official [Gradle YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/GradleInc) incredibly useful; the first video on the fundamentals ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4HICQ-KoV4)) in particular.